# Is there any easier and shorter way to do this code? [PHP, Loops, Arrays]

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a code to modify the data that comes up from external API. However, I didn't like my code. I believe that there is a shorter way to do.

**let me explain the flow:**

I request to an api endpoint to get currency short codes. I mean `$results` contains these:

```
[0] => EURUSD
[1] => USDTRY
etc...
```

I want to save these as EUR, USD, TRY. I used `str_split` to do this. Also, I used `array_unique` to remove the same values.
Right now, my array contains this.

```
[0] => EUR
[3] => USD
[5] => TRY
```

It's not enough for me. I need to change keys according to my database structure.

My table contains: **id, name, created**
I have to rename each key as **name**. (btw I use Phnix to migrate and seeding)

```
$results = json_decode($httpResponse->getBody());

        $data = [];
        $prepared = [];

        foreach ($results as $key => $item) {
            $data = array_merge($data, str_split($item, 3));
        }

        $data = array_unique($data);

        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            array_push($prepared, ['name' => $item]);
        }

$currency = $this->table('currency');
$currency->truncate();
$currency->insert($prepared)->save();
```

Do you have any clue for the best way?

Comment: Can you share your expected output with the input array?

Comment: What do you mean, *I need to change keys according to my database structure*? And does you code work or not? By the way, it seems that a unique index on the name is really all you need.

Comment: @SahilGulati the code and output are correct actually. I want smarter way to do. Expected output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => EUR ) )

Comment: @jeroen this code is working correctly. I expect the best way from you for loops, etc.if there is better way. of course.

Comment: If the code is working, http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be the appropriate place to ask this.

Comment: @deceze ach so. I didn't know before. thank you.

Comment: You could skip the first lot of merges and just `str_split(implode("",$results),3)` to generate a list of all of the codes.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you make a lot of useless operation: considering that the lenght of the string is always 3 char you can simply use substr to obtain the currency code and use the currency code as key to make your array "unique" (if the same currency is added more than once, will "override" the previous one, whithout affecting the final result).

```
$results = json_decode($httpResponse->getBody());

$prepared = [];
foreach ($results as $item) {
  $itemName = substr($item,0,3);
  $prepared[$itemName] = ['name' => $itemName];
}

$currency = $this->table('currency');
$currency->truncate();
$currency->insert($prepared)->save();
```

Comment: @BilalBaraz This answer will be helpful for you..try this..

Comment: 1. You are missing the second half of the strings and 2. You are not removing the duplicate values. Using the currency code as a key would solve the second problem.

Comment: @SahilGulati: you're right, I'm sorry, I'm pretty new in writing answer...

Comment: @jeroen: edited, adding the second problem and an explanation as suggested by Sahil Gulati ;)

Comment: You're still missing the second half of the string but the OP can figure that out :-)

Comment: it is different a bit. **substr** is incorrect choice already. str_split is good. and the code needs to remove the same values. not only rename the their keys.

Comment: @BilalBaraz Using the name as the key you will overwrite and effectively remove the duplicate values. And you can use `substr()` for the second half as well or stick with `str_split()`, both will do the job with the input you have shown.